# Quick Return (autohide actionbar when scrolling) for Webview

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview, hide

I added a `ScrollListener` to an `ObservableWebView`. I want to achieve the same effect as Chrome or Firefox where the actionbar gets hidden when user scrolls down and shown when user scrolls up. I got this almost working. I have a `marginTop` on the `webView` (to see the top of the webpage visiting) and removes that when the user scrolled more than toolbar height.

The problem is that the `webView` is flickering when changing the margin since the scroll is changing, I dont know how to get around this. I saw someone using a timer but not sure.

This is what I got so far:

```
webView.setOnScrollChangedCallback((currentX, currentY) -> {

    int sensitivity = (int) dp48;
    int deltaY = prevScroll - currentY;
    prevScroll = currentY;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    if (currentY > dp48 && atTop) {
        atTop = false;
        params.topMargin = 0;
        webView.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else if (currentY < dp48 && !atTop) {
        atTop = true;
        params.topMargin = (int) dp48;
        webView.setLayoutParams(params);
    } else {
        if (deltaY > sensitivity) {
            deltaY = sensitivity;
        } else if (deltaY < -sensitivity) {
            deltaY = -sensitivity;
        }
        if (Math.signum(deltaY) * Math.signum(actionBarAutoHideSignal) < 0) {
            // deltaY is a motion opposite to the accumulated signal, so reset signal
            actionBarAutoHideSignal = deltaY;
        } else {
            // add to accumulated signal
            mActionBarAutoHideSignal += deltaY;
        }
        boolean shouldShow = currentY < 0 || (actionBarAutoHideSignal <= -sensitivity);
        autoShowOrHideActionBar(shouldShow);
    }
});

private void autoShowOrHideActionBar(boolean hide) {
    if (hide == toolbarShowing) {
        return;
    }

    toolbarShowing = hide;

    if (hide) {
        toolbar.animate()
                .translationY(-toolbar.getBottom())
                .alpha(0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    } else {
        toolbar.animate()
                .translationY(0)
                .alpha(1)
                .setDuration(300)
                .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/web_view_container_rail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="gone">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/left_shadow"
        android:layout_width="6dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/dropshadow_left"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/web_view_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffff">
        <com.onedepth.search.view.BounceProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/web_view_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:elevation="8dp">
        </com.onedepth.search.view.BounceProgressBar>
        <com.onedepth.search.view.ObservableWebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>
        <!--<include layout="@layout/toolbar_dropshadow"/>!-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/webview_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/web_view_close"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/x"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="192dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/web_view_reload"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/replay"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/web_view_action"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/stack_icon_on"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/web_view_screenshot"
                    android:layout_width="48dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/screenshot"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/web_view_overflow"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/overflow"
                    android:scaleType="center"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at what other browsers are doing and I found a very interesting [discussion](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=427445) about this. Here's the options I found to achieve this without having the scroll flickering as the toolbar hides/shows:

1. Heres a [pdf](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1vHXijJqm011cfupbcNmQMI1HdA2lZ0ZjjirwRTwmVtk/edit#slide=id.g2b009779f_096) briefly explaining what **Chrome** (And **Firefox**?) is doing. **Chrome** is changing the Chromium WebView, it seems pretty hacky and I didn't even get into the details.
2. **Opera**, **Apus Browser** and some other does not resize the webview but setting height to `screenHeight - toolbarHeight` and simply having a static toolbar at the bottom where the webview hides under when top toolbar is showing. The webview itself is moved up and down.
3. Other browsers like **CM** and **Mercury** setting equal `topMargin` and `bottomMargin` to the webview and animates them together. This is nice because increasing top and bottom margin at the same time avoids making the scrollbar jump. Also, the performance is better than I expected.
4. **UC browser** is having a button that you click to show the toolbars and it hides again when scrolling.